# Java Android: send a picture I have just captured

Tags: java, android, email, camera

I am trying to create an app that calls the camera app to take a picture. The capture picture is displayed in my app and I would like it to be automatically sent by email to an address defined in the Java code, on click of a "Send" Button. When I test my app on the emulator, it crashes on click of the "Send" button.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B = 1;

private static final String BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY = "viewbitmap";
private static final String IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "imageviewvisibility";
private ImageView mImageView;
private Bitmap mImageBitmap;

Button RecAudio, Send;
EditText nomMachine; 
TextView machine;

private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";

private AlbumStorageDirFactory mAlbumStorageDirFactory = null;


/* Photo album for this application */
private String getAlbumName() {
    return getString(R.string.album_name);
}


private File getAlbumDir() {
    File storageDir = null;

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

        storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());

        if (storageDir != null) {
            if (! storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                if (! storageDir.exists()){
                    Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
    }

    return storageDir;
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
    File albumF = getAlbumDir();
    File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
    return imageF;
}

private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

    File f = createImageFile();
    mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

    return f;
}

private void setPic() {

    /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
    /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

    /* Get the size of the ImageView */
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    /* Get the size of the image */
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
    int scaleFactor = 1;
    if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
        scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH); 
    }

    /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

    /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    switch(actionCode) {
    case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B:
        File f = null;

        try {
            f = setUpPhotoFile();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            f = null;
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;          
    } // switch

    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
}

private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void handleBigCameraPhoto() {

    if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
        setPic();
        galleryAddPic();
        //mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
    }

}

Button.OnClickListener mTakePicOnClickListener = 
        new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);
    }
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mImageBitmap = null;
    nomMachine = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    machine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    RecAudio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    Button picBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIntend);
    setBtnListenerOrDisable( 
            picBtn, 
            mTakePicOnClickListener,
            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
            );

    RecAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent openRecordAudio = new Intent("com.example.daletcruncher.RecordAudio");
            startActivity(openRecordAudio);
        }
    });

    Send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String objet;
            objet = nomMachine.getText().toString();

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "matthieu.dischamps@canal-plus.com");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, objet + timeStamp);

            if(mCurrentPhotoPath!=null) {
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mCurrentPhotoPath);
                emailIntent.setType("image/png");
            }else{
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            }

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choisir app pour l'envoi d'email:"));
        }
    });


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
    } else {
        mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            handleBigCameraPhoto();
        }
        break;
    } // ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B

    } // switch

}
```

Comment: Whats the trace of the crash?

Comment: Without a stacktrace, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Off the top of my head, the emulator may not have anything available to handle that Intent. If the Exception is a ActivityNotFoundException, that is your issue. Run it on a device and you should be fine.

Comment: emulators DO NOT have, by default, an email program. I'd bet $10 that is why it crashed - nothing to handle the intent